# Value cannot be null from JsonSoft in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I have the following JSON content:

```
{
  "name": "alex",
  "age": 23,
  "codes": {
    "1233": 1.2,
    "1234": 2,
    "1443": 2.4
  }
}
```

In VB.NET, I get the values into variables like this:

```
Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonContent)

Dim name as String = o.SelectToken("name");
Dim age as Integer = o.SelectToken("age");
Dim codes as JObject = o.SelectToken("codes");
```

I can see that *name* and *age* are correctly parsed but if I want to get the value of a code from `codes`, I get an error about the value being null (what value, I don't know)

```
Dim code As Double = codes.SelectToken("1234")
' An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred 
' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
' Additional information: Value cannot be null
```

In the **Autos** window I see that the value of codes is `{{ "1233": 1.2, "1234": 2, "1443": 2.5 }}`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not compile using `Option Strict`.

```
Dim codes As JObject = jobj.SelectToken("codes")
Dim code As Double = codes.SelectToken("1234")
```

`SelectToken` returns a `JToken` which inherits from `System.Object` which is different than a `JObject`. The same for the `Double` implicit cast. This works:

```
Dim jobj = JObject.Parse(jstr)

Console.WriteLine(jobj("name"))
Console.WriteLine(jobj("age"))

Console.WriteLine(jobj("codes")("1233"))
Console.WriteLine(jobj("codes")("1234"))
Console.WriteLine(jobj("codes")("1443"))
```

> alex
>   23
>   1.2
>   2
>   2.4

For typed variables:

```
Dim name As String = jobj("name").ToString()
Dim codes = jobj("codes")

' .Item is optional
Dim a As Double = Convert.ToDouble(codes("1233"))
Dim b As Double = Convert.ToDouble(codes.Item("1234"))
Dim c As Double = Convert.ToDouble(codes.Item("1443"))
```

Of course, if you are consuming each element in it, you probably should consider deserializing it.